# How to make app available for testing only after unpublished production apk

Tags: android, google-play

I put my app in alpha testing so only people with the link could download it.
I then published my production apk to the app store. I then found a couple bugs
and decided to unpublish it. I want to put back it to alpha testing and make it available for people to download, but only to people that have the link.

Comment: You can provide a new apk with larger version code

Answer (score 0):

Just upload it again to Alpha channel and be sure that it is in open alpha testing mode. If you are using Gradle before generating the new apk increase the versionName and versionCode attributes.

Comment: I uploaded a new apk to alpha with a higher version name & version code then the production, but it says that opt in link will become available when I publish the app. If I republish , I only want the alpha to be active, I do not want the production to go back onto the app store.

Comment: What happens if I deactivate the production apk? As its after going live on the App Store. I only wanted the alpha to be downloadable by link